# как получить только аргументы функции которая передается как параметр js

Tags: javascript

```
var complexFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {};
var cachedFunction = cache(complexFunction);
function cache(func) {
return function(){
    func.apply(this, arguments);
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
};}
cachedFunction('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: проблема в том, что вместе с параметрами передаются еще функции которые не объявлены, я не пойму что это за функции и как их убрать.

Comment: Вы о чем вообще?

Comment: arguments = ["foo", "bar", callee: function, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function]   получается такой результат, как получить только foo и bar

Comment: `arguments` - это псевдомассив, поэтому вы и получаете `arguments.calee`, используйте `slice` для преобразовывания этого псевдомассива `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`